# Google Cloud Dataprep Import Recipes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I can see it's possible to download a recipe but I can't see any option to import it, does anyone know if there is this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on [`Recipe Options`](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Recipe-Panel_57344894#recipe-options)

> Wrangle recipes are stored in the Cloud Dataprep database. You **cannot** upload new or modified recipes to the platform

Comment: One possible workaround is that you download the .wrangle file and open it in any text editor. If you add a new step in a recipe you can copy a single line from the .wrangle file and paste it in the "search" box. It will instantly convert the copied text to the command, including any fields/values.